# Density Function And Absolute Continuity Of Random Variable $\frac 1 X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution $P_X$  and density $f$ and cdf $F_X$. and  $X$ take  only positive values .that is $$ P_X \left( (-\infty,0]\right)=0$$.
I want to find density  of $\frac 1 X$. If  we know that $\frac 1 X$ is absolutely continuous  then by finding CDF  of $\frac 1 X$ using $F_X$ we can calculate density of $\frac 1 X$ .I want to show $\frac 1 X$ is absolutely continuous.
for $t>0$

$$
\begin{align}
P\left( \frac 1 X \leq t\right) &= P\left( \frac 1 t \leq X\right)\\~~\\
&=\int_{[\frac 1 t,\infty)} f ~~d\lambda\\~\\
&=\int_{(0,t]} f\left(\frac1 m\right)\cdot \frac {-1}{m^2} ~~d\lambda
\end{align}
$$
Now from equation $(5)$ I want  to prove
$$ \int_{(0,t]} f\left(\frac1 m\right)\cdot \frac {-1}{m^2} ~~d\lambda=\int_{(-\infty,t]} f\left(\frac1 m\right)\cdot \frac {-1}{m^2} ~~d\lambda$$

To conclude that  $f\left(\frac 1 m\right)\cdot \frac {-1}{m^2}$ is density of $\frac 1 X$.

The missing part is

$$\int_{(-\infty,0]} f\left(\frac1 m\right)\cdot \frac {-1}{m^2} ~~d\lambda$$ and we have that

$$\int_{(-\infty,0]} f\cdot  ~d\lambda =0$$
How I can add missing part using above equation?

Comment: A more direct approach is to note that $g(x) = 1/x$ mapping $(0, \infty)$ onto $(0, \infty)$ is a $C^1$ function that is invertible, so you can apply the change of variables to obtain the density for $g(X)$.

Comment: @Kakashi Yes .But it is same as differentiate CDF.